# Hash Join with Partition restriction from third table

Tags: oracle

my current problem is in 11g, but I am also interested in how this might be solved smarter in later versions.

I want to join two tables. Table A has 10 million rows, Table B is huge and has a billion of records across about a thousand partitions. One partition has around 10 million records. I am not joining on the partition key. For most rows of Table A, one or more rows in Table B will be found. 
Example:

```
select * from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.ref = b.ref
```

The above will return about 50 million rows, whereas the results come from about 30 partitions of table b. I am assuming a hash join is the correct join here, hashing table a and FTSing/index-scanning table b.

So, 970 partitions were scanned for no reason. And, I have a third query that could tell oracle which 30 partitions to check for the join.
Example of third query:

```
select partition_id from table_c
```

This query gives exactly the 30 partitions for the query above.

To my question:

In PL/SQL one can solve this by

1. select the 30 partition_ids into a variable (be it just a `select listagg(partition_id,',') ... into v_partitions from table_c`
2. Execute my query like so:

   ```
   execute immediate 'select * from table_a a 
   inner join table_b b on a.ref = b.ref 
   where b.partition_id in ('||v_partitions||')' into ...
   ```

Let's say this completes in 10 minutes.

Now, how can I do this *in the same amount of time* with pure SQL?

Just simply writing

```
select * from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.ref = b.ref 
where b.partition_id in (select partition_id from table_c)
```

does not do the trick it seems, or I might be aiming at the wrong plan.

The plan I think I want is

```
hash join
    table a
    nested loop
       table c
       partition pruning here
           table b
```

But, this does not come back in 10 minutes.

So, how to do this in SQL and what execution plan to aim at? One variation I have not tried yet that might be the solution is

```
nested loop
   table c
   hash join
       table a
       partition pruning here (pushed predicate from the join to c)
            table b
```

Another feeling I have is that the solution might lie in joining table a to table c (not sure on what though) and then joining this result to table b.

I am not asking you to type everything out for me. Just a general concept of how to do this (getting partition restriction from a query) in SQL - what plan should I aim at?

thank you very much! Peter

Comment: A test case with tables and data would really help. Also I don't think the join method (hash) is really relevant to your question, which is about partition-wise joins in general.

Comment: The "general concept" is that the Oracle optimiser will attempt to push and transfer predicates and apply partition elimination where it is logically possible to do so, so you should just write the joins as normal (either an `in (subquery)` as you have tried, or just a straight join with C), and it should eliminate unnecessary partitions. If that is not happening then a test case that reproduces the issue will be needed.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson hi. partition elimination is happening. for example in the plan where i write "The plan I think I want is". But the thing is that the PL/SQL version is still way faster. If no one points me to a silver bullet solution in the next few days, I will provide a test case here for you. ty.kr

Comment: This would be an interesting question if you provided a test case. Otherwise I think my general comment above is the nearest you will get to an answer.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson please see the answer I wrote below. Unfortunately, as this is solved for me now and as the test case would include loads of data, I will not provide the test case anymore. Hopefully, the answer I wrote is interesting to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your discussions with me on this one. In my case this was solved (not by me) by adding a join-path between table_c and table_a and by overloading the join conditions as below. In my case this was possible by adding column partition_id to table_a:

```
select * from
  table_c c
  JOIN table_a a ON (a.partition_id = c.partition_id)
  JOIN table_b b ON (b.partition_id = c.partition_id and b.partition_id = a.partition_id and b.ref = a.ref)
```

And this is the plan you want:

```
leading(c,b,a) use_nl(c,b) swap_join_inputs(a) use_hash(a)
```

So you get:

```
hash join
    table a
    nested loop
       table c
       partition list iterator
           table b
```

Comment: Are all three tables partitioned? By the way there is no bracket in `join` syntax.

Comment: only the huge table, table_b is partitioned. table_c is a small table with 30 rows and only one column partition_id. it is the result of `select distinct partition_id from table_a`. table_a is an intermediary results table with 10 million rows and no partitions, but in the final solution we went for storing partition_id on top of ref for each row of table_a to make the join and partition pruning work. Maybe I find time this week to compile a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at this, but I think Oracle generally does the joins first, then applies the where conditions. So you might get the plan you want by moving the partition pruning up into a join condition:

```
select * from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.ref = b.ref 
  and b.partition_id in (select partition_id from table_c);
```

I've also seen people try to do this sort of thing with an inline view:

```
select * from table_a a
inner join (select * from table_b
            where partition_id in (select partition_id from table_c)) b
on a.ref = b.ref;
```

Comment: ty. I think I tried all these variations already. the thing is - I think - you always end up with 2 joins in one of these 3 orders: a+(b+c)  b+(c+a) c+(a+b), however you write the query. then, they might also vary in terms of other parts of the execution plan like NL vs hash-join etc... but i have not yet seen a plan that is as fast as the PL/SQL version that I state above. The thing is that I do not want to use PL/SQL here. So my question is: What execution plan can do this exercise as fast as the PL/SQL can. TY. Peter

Comment: Oracle doesn't do the joins first then the `where` clause.

Comment: Hi William - this seems to say that with ANSI joins, Oracle applies join conditions first, then applies where conditions to the result. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9522421800346573383

Comment: The AskTOM post appears to be about `where` clause conditions with outer joins. The questioner expected `where b.col_b <> 5` to still produce rows after outer joining to `b` when there was no corresponding row in `b`. That doesn't mean the Oracle optimiser is constrained to join first and filter afterwards.